# How to fetch RSS feed data in angular2

Tags: google-api, rss, angular2-services

I have tried

```
getRSSFeed(url) {
    return this.http.get('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url), { headers: this.header2 })
      .map((res) => res.json());
  }
```

I am getting 200 status and getting error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.example.com%2Ffeed. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I like to fetch as json format so i have used like this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=http://blog.example.com/feed

Comment: There is nothing Angular related. The server needs to allow CORS requests.

Comment: can you please say how to fix this

Comment: i am using google api https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=

Comment: I guess you need to create your question in a Google API tag. It's not Angular related.